# I have three legs. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I have three legs.
>
> I represent zeros and ones.
>
> I am the 20th century, most important invention.
>
> I am the most evolved piece of technology in history.
>
> I am a building block for the processor.

Who am I?

Comment: I've downvoted this puzzle because it takes literal aspects of an object and describes them directly, and shows minimal effort to create a well-developed puzzle.

Comment: I've downvoted because of the same reasons as Emrakul, basically. Also note that the riddle tag says: _"A riddle gives_ *indirect clues* _about an unnamed object [...]"_. In my opinion you've had the right idea and simply described the object but didn't provide clues, especially not _indirect_ ones.

Comment: Down vote from me for same reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it

> Transistor [image]

I have a three legs.

> It has three pins.

I am representing zeros and ones.

> Resistor–transistor logic (RTL)

I am most important invention of the 20th century.

> yes it is.

I am most evolved piece of technology in history.

> The first transistor was about the size of the palm of a hand, with a depth of two matchbooks stacked on top of each other. Now it is in **NM**.

I am building block for the processor.

> transistor is the building block for the processor.

Comment: right answer...

Comment: im amazed by the current size of them. ... nanometers :O a few atoms

Comment: @lois: That's still *way* bigger than the atomic scale.

Comment: @Deusovi: Well, only one order of magnitude. Atomic diameter ranges from 0.1 to 0.5nm. So, actually, lois is correct.

Answer (score 2):

> Computer/code

I have three legs.

> Monitor, mouse, and keyboard

I am representing zeros and ones.

> Computers work in binary

I am most important invention of the 20th century.

> It is.

I am most evolved piece of technology in history.

> Yeah...

I am building block for the processor.

> :/

Answer (score 2):

My guess:

> Transistor

I have a three legs.

> Transistor have three legs.

I am representing zeros and ones.

> Yes its representing 0s and 1s in memory organisation.